# Passing package name as argument in R

Tags: r, function

I see myself keep using the `install.package` function a lot especially when I have to try out someone else's code or run an example.

I as writing a function that installs and loads a package. I tried the following but it did not work:

```
inp <- function(PKG)
{
  install.packages(deparse(substitute(PKG)))
  library(deparse(substitute(PKG)))
}
```

When I typed `inp(data.table)`, it says

```
Error in library(deparse(substitute(PKG))) : 
  'package' must be of length 1
```

How do I pass library name as argument in this case?
I will appreciate if someone can also direct me to information pertaining to passing any kind of object as argument to a function in `R`.

Comment: Have a look at this nice function: https://github.com/gimoya/theBioBucket-Archives/blob/master/R/Functions/instant_pkgs.R

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`library()` is throwing an error because it by default accepts either a character *or* a name as its first argument. It sees `deparse(substitute(PKG))` in that first argument, and understandably can't find a package of that name when it looks for it.

Setting `character.only=TRUE`, which tells `library()` to expect a character string as its first argument, should fix the problem. Try this:

```
f <- function(PKG) {
    library(deparse(substitute(PKG)), character.only=TRUE)
}

## Try it out
exists("ddply")
# [1] FALSE
f(plyr)
exists("ddply")
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I think it would be even better to take `PKG` as a string. Relying on non-standard evaluation leads to code that is difficult to debug.

Comment: @hadley Can you please suggest how do I do this?

Comment: @Stat-R call the function like `f("plyr")`